# Running apscheduler cron at certain interval combining minutes and seconds

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have two cron jobs running at 10 mins interval each. Job2 is dependent on Job1 data. I want to schedule a job where job2 can wait for 30 seconds so that Job1 can have the data.

```
Example
12:00:00 am - job1 running
12:00:30 am - job2 running ( I am sure that data is present by this time for job1)
-----
12:10:00 am - job1 running
12:10:30 am - job2 running ( I am sure that data is present by this time for job1)
```

I tried 'interval' as trigger and minutes set to 10 and seconds to 30 but it leads to something like

```
12:00:00 am - job1 running
12:00:30 am - job2 running
-------
12:10:00 am - job1 running
12:11:00 am - job2 running
```

Is there a way to run both the jobs at a difference of 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

```
scheduler.add_job(job1, 'cron', minute='*/10')
scheduler.add_job(job2, 'cron', minute='*/10', second=30)
```

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html